# How can I fill third edt text automatically. When I fill the first two edittexts?

Tags: android

I want to enter two float values in two `EditText`s and the third `EditText` should fill automatically.

Example:  `49.6*25.7 = New Value`

How can I do this?

Comment: It depends how you want it to act. You could add a button or clic in the edittext to fill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String val1 = edit1.getText();
String val2 = edit2.getText();

double product = Float.parseFloat(val1) * Float.parseFloat(val2);

edit3.setText(""+product);
```

Have some default values in your edittext like 0. Then set focus change listener to the third text edit text. In the callback, calculate the value and set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**For the first EditText**

```
EditText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        EditText3.setText(“Your Mathematics Formula”);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**For the second EditText**

```
EditText2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        EditText3.setText(“Your Mathematics Formula”);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Formula**

```
String e1 = EditText1.getText().toString();
String e2 = EditText2.getText().toString();

double e3 = Float.parseFloat(e1) * Float.parseFloat(e2);

EditText3.setText(""+e3);
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you get `clicked on third edittext or get focus` then you can check if the above two edittext have values or not and accordingly you can set values in third edittext.